# React set initial state to array of objects

Tags: reactjs, axios

This is probably a super simple question but I seem to be finding various answers to. Essentially I have an app that makes an axios call to get a list of items via JSON API.

I need to set the initial state on the component load my state looks like this:

```
this.state = {
  sensors: [],
  filterName: "",
  sortBy: "id",
};
```

my component loading code looks like so:

```
  componentDidMount =() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/devices.json")
      .then((response) => {
        // handle success
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({ sensors: [...response.data]});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
```

This works...but I feel like this isn't the right way. Isn't it not supposed to change the initial array because I remember reading that we shouldn't ever be changing the initial state only returning a new version of it?

Is there a better/safer way?

(Also what about updating a single one/adding an item to array of objects? Is there a "preferred way")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to add elements to the sensors array without directly mutating the state, this is what you can do.

```
const { sensors } = this.state;
this.setState({ 
  sensors: [...sensors, response.data]
});
```

What this does is that we are using the spread syntax to destructure the array, and copy it to a new array with the `response.data` from the API.